# FCM Send via to vs topic vs adding a condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification to a specific user in Flutter with FCM using POST. All users are subscribed to their own uid.

So when I try to send by passing their `uid` to the `to` parameter it doesn't work, which I later realized only tokens work in that field. Then I tried passing the `uid` in the `topic` parameter and that as well failed for I don't know what reason. But finally when I added the value `"'uid' in topics"` in the `condition` parameter it finally worked.

I'm just wondering why only by the `condition` parameter that the notification from device to specific user finally worked instead of the `topic`.

Is there a better way of doing it, sending a notification from device to device on the device instead of cloud functions?

```
Future<bool> sendAlert({Alert alert}) async {
    try {
      var client = http.Client();
      var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
      var headers = <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=$_serverToken',
      };
      var response = await client.post(
        url,
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(
          Alert().map(
            alert: alert,
          ),
        ),
      );
      Funcs.log(response.body);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      Funcs.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

*`Alert()` is just a model I made so I don't have to write the [whole map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message) every time I need it.

Comment: You shouldn't include your server token in client apps, or even make it available to client apps at all.  That's a huge security hole.  It would allow anyone to send messages to any client simply by invoking the FCM API directly.  You should only invoke FCM APIs from secure backend code.

Comment: Also note that topic messaging is not really secure.  Any client can subscribe to any topic if they simply know its name.  Having a per-UID topic for each user would allow anyone to listen in on anyone else's messages.  You should send to direct device tokens associated to that user instead.

Comment: If you have other questions, please post them separately.